# Automate Builds without TFS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, build-process

I have a large c# project that depends on a number of other projects.

I'd like to create\use a build automation script of sorts.

The process would look something like:

```
 - Clone project X from Git, run unit tests, compile. 
 - Clone project Y from Git, run unit tests, compile. 
 - Clone project Z from Git, run unit tests, compile.
```

Project Z depends on Y and Y depends on X.

I'm aware that Team Foundation Server does much of this, but I'm looking for a lighter solution.

What are the open source alternatives to TFS?

Comment: I suppose you are looking for [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) software, I can recommend either [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) or [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/).

Comment: Jenkins is so much better than TFS's build system - ie you can understand how to modify jobs, and all from an easy-to-use web interface. My only complain is that it is a bit java-oriented out of the box where those java build bits should be plugins.

Comment: Of course, you could also use Visual Studio Online, which can use Git for source control while still using the workflow-based TFS Build system. All Pretty Cheap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at teamcity. Much easier to use. We migrated our builds from TFS to teamcity. It's free for upto 3 build agents and 20 build configurations (which is good enough for mid level teams) but the Enterprise version is not that expensive too.

http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/

Jenkins is another option too.

Answer (score 1):

NAnt will also do all the  basic CI tasks, and is open source. http://nant.sourceforge.net/